# add_rewrite_rule() not playing nice with child pages

Tags: url-rewriting

```
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {

  add_rewrite_rule('testing/([^/]+)?$', 'index.php?pagename=testing&event_slug=$matches[1]', 'top' ); 

}
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );

function add_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
  $query_vars[] = 'event_slug';
  return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars' );
```

*/testing/foo* - Works, shows foo

If I have **testing** set to no parent, the rewrite works and everything is good to go.

If I set **testing** to a child of, lets say **about**, and update the add_rewrite_rule to..

```
add_rewrite_rule('about/testing/([^/]+)?$', 'index.php?pagename=testing&event_slug=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

... it loads about/testing but strips out my custom query_var and displays the page normally.

*/about/testing/foo* - Loads page, doesn't show foo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if it's a child page, you have to update `pagename` to reflect the parent/child path:

```
add_rewrite_rule('about/testing/([^/]+)?$', 'index.php?pagename=about/testing&event_slug=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

Comment: Remeber to flush the rewrite cache by click "Save Changes" on "/wp-admin/options-permalink.php".

Comment: You don’t need to click save changes, just loading the permalinks settings page flushes rules.